# How to remove 'Home' from breadcrumbs in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

There are breadcrumbs in my wordpress site like "Home>City"

I want to display only "City" name in the breadcrumb. I dont want to display "Home"

How can I achieve this? Thanks..

This is the code I call the breadcrumbs to my front-end place

```
<?php
        $display_property_breadcrumbs = get_option( 'theme_display_property_breadcrumbs' );
        if ( 'true' == $display_property_breadcrumbs ) {
            get_template_part( 'common/partials/breadcrumbs' );
        }
        ?>
```

And this is my theme's breadcrumbs file

```
<?php
/**
* Breadcrumbs for property detail page.
*
* @package    realhomes
* @subpackage classic
*/

global $post;

$possible_taxonomies  = array( 'property-city', 'property-type', 'property-status' );
$breadcrumbs_taxonomy = get_option( 'theme_breadcrumbs_taxonomy' );
if ( $breadcrumbs_taxonomy && in_array( $breadcrumbs_taxonomy,         $possible_taxonomies ) ) {

$inspiry_breadcrumbs_items = inspiry_get_breadcrumbs_items( $post->ID, $breadcrumbs_taxonomy, false );
$breadcrumbs_count         = count( $inspiry_breadcrumbs_items );

if ( is_array( $inspiry_breadcrumbs_items ) && ( 0 < $breadcrumbs_count ) ) {

    $bread_crumbs_modern = '';
    if ( 'modern' === INSPIRY_DESIGN_VARIATION ) {
        $bread_crumbs_modern = ' page-breadcrumbs-modern';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="page-breadcrumbs <?php echo $bread_crumbs_modern;?>">
        <nav class="property-breadcrumbs">
            <ul>
                <?php
                $breadcrumbs_item_index = 1;
                foreach ( $inspiry_breadcrumbs_items as $item ) {

                    echo '<li>';

                    if ( isset( $item['url'] ) && ! empty( $item['url'] ) ) {
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item['url'] ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $item['name'] ); ?></a><?php
                    } else {
                        echo esc_html( $item['name'] );
                    }

                    $breadcrumbs_item_index ++;
                    if ( $breadcrumbs_item_index <= $breadcrumbs_count ) {
                        if ( is_rtl() ) {
                            ?><i class="breadcrumbs-separator fa fa-angle-left"></i><?php
                        } else {
                            ?><i class="breadcrumbs-separator fa fa-angle-right"></i><?php
                        }
                    }

                    echo '</li>';
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <?php

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_shift

```
array_shift($inspiry_breadcrumbs_items); // Removes the Home item
```

Comment: Where should I add this code? To functions.php file?

Comment: Put that in your  theme's breadcrumbs file. Put it under $inspiry_breadcrumbs_items = inspiry_get_breadcrumbs_items()

Comment: That worked perfectly!! Thank you! Do you think this code could harm my website's SEO? Thanks again!

Comment: No the home page is automaticly visited as long as it remains at the root level of the domain name. You can make the logo return to home if it's not already the case. No need to have that in your breadcrumbs.